# C# to Postman Convert example

Tags: c#, postman

```
reqString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Formatting.Indented));
resByte = wc.UploadData(ServiceAuthorization.URL + @"api/main/setTransactionDetail", "PUT", reqString);
```

How can convert `reqString` Postman Request and which tab use in postman?
I want to Put this operation in Postman. But I have get error every time.

Comment: reqString is not actually a string, it's a byte array. You'd probably want to grab the result of the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Formatting.Indented)` line instead if you're looking to use the JSON in postman.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by converting `reqString` Postman Request ? Postman is used to send requests to services and read their responses.

Answer (score 0):

**First (get the url and JSON body):**

var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Formatting.Indented);
var ulr = ServiceAuthorization.URL + @"api/main/setTransactionDetail";

Console.WriteLine(body);

Console.WriteLine(url);

Then go to **Postman**:
[image]

Hope that helps?